# multiple .on events AND detecting keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

i run a function like this:

```
$(document).on('change, focusout', '.something', function(){ ... }
```

I would like the handler to also execute when keypress == 13.
What's the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a if statement

```
$(document).on('change focusout keypress', '.something', function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13 ) {
//code here
}
 });
```

Comment: Also, no need of `,` in events. and missing `)` at the end

Comment: 1. it doesn't work... could it be browser specific?
2. do i have to refactor the code inside the if block in case it's not an ENTER, which would be the case for change and focusout ?

also, thank you for the fast reply

Comment: I looked at your jsfiddle. Thank you for fast Reply ! The change and focusout don't work. That makes sense right? I should refactor code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change, focusout', '.something', function(e)
{
if(e.keyCode == 13 ) { //some code here }
}
```

Comment: Also, no need of `,` in events. and missing `)` at the end

Comment: @Desmond Chau you realise that this answer was already posted don't you?

Comment: @madalinivascu sorry before I answer I didn't see your answer, after I posted my answer only I saw your answer popped out.

Comment: @madalinivascu do I have to delete my answer? As I'm new here, don't know the rule, anything that offense you i'm sorry about it

Comment: I edited it because my "}" was under comment too, I was trying to add space so that it won't be under comment, but I failed to do so. I type my answer manually, is that wrong to do too? Just trying to help.

Comment: I just saw your originial answer. And when I realized you edited to match the other's answer, I was a bit mindfcked. Sorry if I'm too skeptical, I need some sleep

Comment: It's ok, I like your name anyway. that's what caught my attention to view your questions. brucelee who does javascript.